# Not able to connect to MySQL database when using Apache NiFi in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, apache-nifi

I am trying to connect to a **MySQL** RDS instance in AWS with **Apache NiFi** on **Linux Ubuntu**.

The MySQL database is behind a SSH tunnel which is working in a dedicated terminal. The MySQL database is accessible through another Linux terminal.

```
$ ssh -i /home/bernardo/.ssh/sshbernardo3.pem -N \
-L 33061:<db_name>.<id>.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 \
<user>@<ip_address> -p <port>
```

I have uploaded and unzipped the JDBC driver from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/

The file java.sql.Driver is located in the directory `/usr/share/java/META-INF/services` in Linux

I have installed the jdbc connector in Linux and set up the user to use JDBC

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmysql-java
$ cd /home/bernardo
$ gedit .bashrc
```

Added the following lines at the end of the file:

```
# Setting up the user to use JDBC
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar
export CLASSPATH
```

Then source it:

```
$ source .bashrc
```

In NiFi I have used a DBCPConnectionPool1.15.2 controller service which is configured as follows:

• Database Connection URL: `jbdc:mysql://127.0.0.1:33061/<db_name>`

• Database Driver Class Name: `java.sql.Driver`

• Database Driver Location: `/usr/share/java/META-INF/services`

• Database User: `<db_user>`

• Password: `<db_password>`

When enabling the controller service, I get the following error:

> StandardControllerServiceNode[service=DBCPConnectionPool[id=2440f624-017e-1000-9467-8bb12dda6ca6],
> name=<controller_service_name>, active=true] Failed to invoke
> @OnEnabled method due to java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> java.sql.Driver.() causes: java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.sql.Driver causes:
> org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Creating driver
> instance is failed: Creating driver instance is failed

Any hint?

This is the SW I have installed:

- Linux Ubuntu 18.04.6 in VirtualBox 6.1 on top of Windows 10 Pro
- openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
- javac 11.0.13
- nifi-1.15.2

Thanks,

Bernardo

---

EDITED on 2022 January 6 08:50 UTC

I have made the following changes to the DBCPConnectionPool1.15.2 controller service configuration:

• Database Driver Class Name: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

• Database Driver Location: `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar`

The other parameters are not changed:

• Database Connection URL: `jbdc:mysql://127.0.0.1:33061/<db_name>`

• Database User: `<db_user>`

• Password: `<db_password>`

The file `mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar` is in `/usr/share/java`

Also:

```
$ cat /usr/share/java/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

And:

```
$ netstat -nplt

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State PID/Program name

tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:33061 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 4873/ssh
tcp6 0 0 ::1:33061 :::* LISTEN 4873/ssh
```

Still I get an error (a **new error** this time):

> causes: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: No suitable driver for the given Database Connection URL

Permissions to access the driver jar file:

```
bernardo@BDi-laptop:/usr/share/java$ ls -l

-rwxrwxr-- 1 bernardo bernardo 2462344 gen  4 19:01 mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar
```

---

EDITED on 2022 January 6 10:21 UTC

Added the CLASSPATH variable also in /etc/environment

```
bernardo@BDi-laptop:/usr/share/java$ echo $CLASSPATH
.:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar
```

---

EDITED on 2022 January 7 09:08 UTC

I thought it could be an issue related to the **driver version** so I re-installed the jdbc driver. I have cleaned `/home/bernardo/Download` and `/usr/share/java` from the old sql related files. Then I have done the installation again.

Install the jdbc connector

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmysql-java
```

The .jar file is in `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar`
Unpack the .jar file

```
$ sudo jar xvf /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar
```

To find the driver class name, open `/usr/share/java/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`

```
$ cat /usr/share/java/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver
```

The driver class name is: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

This is the updated configuration in the DBCPConnectionPool1.15.2 controller service in Apache Ni-Fi:

• Database Driver Class Name: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

• Database Driver Location: `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar`

• Database Connection URL: `jbdc:mysql://127.0.0.1:33061/<db_name>`

• Database User: `<db_user>`

• Password: `<db_password>`

I have obtained the same result:

> causes: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: No suitable driver for the given Database Connection URL

Then I checked if the problem was in the **SSH tunnel**.

```
$ netstat -nplt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address          State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33061         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4497/ssh
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                              
tcp6       0      0 ::1:33061               :::*                    LISTEN      4497/ssh     

$ cat /proc/4497/status

Name:   ssh
State:  S (sleeping)
```

The SSH process is in sleeping state.

In a separate terminal I accessed the remote MySQL database:

```
$ mysql -u <db_user> -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 33061
```

Finally, I tried to connect to my local mysql database in my local Linux instance by using the following Ni-Fi settings:

• Database Driver Class Name: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

• Database Driver Location: `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar`

• Database Connection URL: `jbdc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/<local_db_name>`

• Database User: `<local_db_user>`

• Password: `<local_db_password>`

I have obtained the same result:

> causes: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: No suitable driver for the given Database Connection URL

Still, in a separate Linux terminal I am able to access the local mysql database:

```
$ mysql -u <local_db_user> -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
```

---

EDITED on 2022 January 10 11:58 UTC

Corrected a typo in Ni-Fi controller service configuration:

• Database Connection URL: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:33061/<db_name>

Controller service problem solved!

Thanks!

---

EDITED on 2022 January 12 08:26 UTC

I am still getting connectivity problems. I managed to enable the controller service but, when I run the processor QueryDatabaseTable, I get the following error: **Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory - Communications link failure**

> QueryDatabaseTable[id=017e1003-c2d8-14cf-4e34-feee76411595] Unable to execute SQL select query SELECT * FROM periodic_measurements_test due to java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 0 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
> ↳ causes: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 0 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
> ↳ causes: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 0 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.)
> ↳ causes: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 0 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.)

The processor configuration is default except for:

• Database Connection Pooling Service: < DBCPConnectionPool controller service name >

• Database Type: MySQL

• Table Name: periodic_measurements_test

The controller service configuration is still:

• Database Connection URL: `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:33061/<db_name>`

• Database Driver Class Name: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

• Database Driver Location: `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar`

• Database User: `<db_user>`

• Password: `<db_password>`

The SSH tunnel seems to be fine:

```
netstat -nplt

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33061         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29483/ssh           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                                      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8443          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

And in Linux terminal I can still access the MySQL database thorough CLI:

```
$ mysql -u <db_user> -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 33061
```

And I get the same result when I try to fetch data from the MySQL database in my local Linux instance.

Comment: Classpath is present on bash? what does 'env' say

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Nifi can not load MySQL driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66054305/apache-nifi-can-not-load-mysql-driver)

Comment: What happens if you point the `Database Driver Location` directly at the jar? e.g. `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar` or wherever your jar is located?

Comment: in nifi log file there should be more information about exception reason.

Comment: @mahatmanich

$ sudo nano /etc/environment

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"

JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"

Comment: @Nic3500, thanks for your comments! I have edited the original post with my changes.

Comment: @Sdairs, thanks for your comments! I have edited the original post with my changes.

Comment: @BerniHacker with `Database Driver Location` pointing directly at the file, you can ignore the classpath, it's irrelevant. This is a different error message - it is now finding the file. However, the Driver you've supplied does not seem to like the JDBC URL you are providing. Have you tried `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` for the `Database Driver Class Name`?

Comment: Looking in nifi-app.log may provided a more detailed error message to go on as well

Comment: @Sdairs nifi-app.log does not give additional information

Comment: @Sdairs I tried with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (see 2022 January 7 09:08 UT update)

Comment: Hmmm weird - are you perhaps copy/pasting the URL into the box in Nifi? If so, can you try manually typing it and see if it behaves differently? Silly I know, but atm Nifi takes the first clipboard result and not always the text/plain one.

Comment: @Sdairs Thanks! That has helped even though it was not the root cause. Still, it has helped to notice a typo in the URL: jbdc > jdbc

Comment: Haha, classic! Happy NiFi'ing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to fix the issue. It was related to the version of the jdbc driver.

I did the following:

In Linux browser go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Select

•   Ubuntu Linux

•   18.04

Download

In a CLI terminal go to the Downloads directory

```
$ cd /home/bernardo/Downloads
```

Unpack the deb file

```
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-connector-java_8.0.26-1ubuntu18.04_all.deb
```

Check where is the connector location in the file system

```
$ dpkg -L mysql-connector-java | fgrep jar

/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar
```

Clean /usr/share/java from the previous jdbc driver

```
$ sudo rm mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar
$ sudo rm -r com
$ sudo rm -r META-INF/
```

Install the connector: unpack the .jar file

```
$ sudo jar xvf /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar
```

To find the driver class name, open /usr/share/java/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver

```
$ cat /usr/share/java/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

The driver class name is: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Restart Apache Ni-Fi

Modify the configuration of the controller service with:

• Database Driver Class Name: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

• Database Driver Location: `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar`